# How to call a procedure inside another procedure in snowflake

Tags: javascript, sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Here is my stored procedure that retrieves all the column names of a table. I want to call this procedure inside another procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_columns(TABLE_NAME VARCHAR)
RETURNS ARRAY
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
var stmt = snowflake.createStatement({
    sqlText: "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " LIMIT 1;",    
});
stmt.execute();

var cols=[];
for (i = 1; i <= stmt.getColumnCount(); i++) {
  cols.push(stmt.getColumnName(i));
}
return cols
$$;
```

Below is the main procedure that calls the above procedure and return an array of column names. But I don't understand where I'm going wrong.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_data()   //procedure call the above procedure
    RETURNS ARRAY
    LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
    AS
    $$
    var arr = [];
    var r = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "call get_columns('Table_Name')"});
    arr = r.execute();  //r.execute() returns an array
    return arr; //getting an error
    $$
```

Comment: Whats your error message/output? So what is going wrong exactly?

Comment: @Marcel I'm getting "Return value is not an ARRAY"

Comment: @Marcel This is returning an [object Object]

Comment: Curious why you're using SP's to return ARRAYs, rather than using a UDTF and returning a table.  Might work better for you...

Comment: @Marcel, Nevermind, I figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any "big" errors... maybe adding a semicolon after the call get_columns('Table_Name') is helping? (for me it's also working without the semicolon here, so I think this is not the problem)

On top of that there is no semicolon after $$ in the end (maybe some later code in your script is causing the error then)

Additional information can be found here https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/stored-procedures-overview.html#stored-procedures-are-called-as-independent-statements

One last hint may be access rights to your table.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you have is that you didn't iterate on the resultset arr. You can do the following in your code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_data()   //procedure call the above procedure
  RETURNS ARRAY
  LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
  AS
  $$
  var arr = [];
  var r = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: "call get_columns('TABLE_NAME')"});
  arr = r.execute();
  arr.next();
  return arr.getColumnValue(1);
  $$;
    
call get_data();
```